# Lithuanian currency symbol still showing as LT under .NET application

Tags: .net, vb.net, internationalization, .net-3.5

My .NET 3.5 applications are not using the Euro for Lithuania, but instead still show the former LT symbol when formatting currency. When running the following code:

```
Dim ci As New CultureInfo("lt-LT", False)
Dim amount As Decimal = 123.56
Label1.Text = amount.ToString("c", ci)
```

I get the following result: 123,56 Lt

I should be getting: 123,56 €

I have several computers that behave in this way. All have KB3006137 installed, which is supposed to change the Lt to €. What's odd is that the Regional Formatting dialog in Windows shows €, so I know that KB3006137 has taken effect. However, .NET applications do not seem to pick up on this change and continue to use the former Lt.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling KB3006137, but the results are the same. Even on Windows 10, some computers show € and others show Lt. Any ideas on what's happening here? Is .NET possibly caching Lt instead of retrieving €?

Comment: What version of Windows is this? How is your Regional control-panel set-up? What user account is your program running under?

Comment: i think .net maintains a separate list of culture info. you could try to build your own with `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`

Comment: Dai: I have reproduced this on multiple computers running Windows 7, 8.1, and 10. The simple test app has been run under both Administrator and Standard user accounts, with and without UAC.

Comment: Daniel: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't think .NET maintained a separate list since you can change settings in the Region area of Windows and that will be reflected in the .NET app.